# Jquery validate - how to require specific options from drop down menu to be selected before validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

If I require one specific option frpm drop down menu to be selected before validation of some field, I do like this:

```
required: "#employmentStatusSTUDENT:selected",
```

How can I make this requirement to be applied also in case other option is selected?

Something like:

```
required: "#employmentStatusSTUDENT:selected||#employmentStatusEMPLOYEED:selected",
```

doesn't work of course...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you could do this similar to how a checkbox or radio is done.
Instead of making an option required, set the required to the select node.
then give the list of required options a class. I used 'myRequiredOptions:selected'.

required: "#mySelect > option.myRequiredOptions:selected"

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous function

```
required: function(){return $("#employmentStatusSTUDENT:selected")||$("#employmentStatusEMPLOYEED:selected");}
```